# конвертация из input datetime в timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

Добрый день, есть форма с  с которого я получаю дату в формате "yyyy-mm-ddТH:M". Нужно получить в формате timestamp. Сделал свою функцию, но не возвращает почему-то вменяемо значение. Вместо вводимой даты получаю 1999 год. Подскажите пожалуйста, на каком этапе в функции я допустил ошибку?

```
<?php
$datic = '2016-06-10T10:10';
echo create_timestamp($datic);
function create_timestamp($datic){
    $date = str_replace("T", " ", $datic); //убираю лишнюю Т 
    $strf = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M');
    $dt = strptime ($date, $strf);
    return mktime($dt['tm_hour'], $dt['tm_min'], $dt['tm_sec'],  $dt['tm_mon'],  $dt['tm_mday'],  $dt['tm_year']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$datic = '2016-06-10T10:10';
echo strtotime($datic); //1465546200
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($datic)); //2016-06-10T10:10
```

Answer (score 1):

А почему DateTime не используете, есть какие-то ограничения?

```
$datic = '2016-06-10T10:10';
$dateTime = new DateTime($datic);
echo $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Данный метод работает, но я не получаю точного результата. Например $datic = '2016-06-10T10:10' в timestamp - 1465567800, если перевести это обратно, то получится непонятка со временем. В исходном варианте время 10:10, а в полученном 14:10

Comment: А часовой пояс вы учитываете?